# Pagination on $group aggregation query

Tags: mongodb

I've a MongoDB collection "products". With the following query, I'm succesfully grouping the products by category and counting the number of element for each category.

```
db.products.aggregate
([
    {
        $group:{_id:"$category",count:{"$sum":1}}
    }
]);
```

Unfortunately the number of categories is really high and I want to implement a pagination mechanism. I've tried with $skip and $limit but the same exact query with same exact $skip/$limit parameters is not returning always the same list of categories. example:

```
db.products.aggregate
([
    {
        $group:{_id:"$category",count:{"$sum":1}}
    },
    {$skip: 10},
    {$limit: 10}
]);
```

What is the correct way to implement such pagination?

Thank you

Davide

Comment: You can `$sort` by *category* before `$skip`. You'll always get the same results in this case.

Comment: As suggested in the previous comment, you can use $sort. A share a simple example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Lw-Wa3oY37t